# Handle 10MHz GPIO interrupt in Linux kernel v3.4.113

Tags: linux, interrupt, gpio

I have Allwinner h3 1.2GHz clock board that run Linux kernel v3.4.113. I need to receive parallel data with clock 10MHz like below picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVkfD.png)
but the GPIO interrupt is very slow in the kernel driver, it handles only 500 interrupts per second. Any solution for this problem?

I use below code, the results of counter must be 10,000,000, but it is such as 1200,700,1000,900, ...

```c
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

#define GPIO_IN 6

unsigned long counter=0;

static irqreturn_t my_handler(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    counter++;
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static int __init exemple_init (void)
{
    int err, i = 0;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Loading GPIO module\n");

    if ((err = gpio_request(GPIO_IN, THIS_MODULE->name)) !=0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO Request Error\n");
        return err;
    }

    if ((err = gpio_direction_input(GPIO_IN)) !=0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO Direction Error\n");
        return err;
    }

    if ((err = request_irq(gpio_to_irq(GPIO_IN), my_handler, IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING, THIS_MODULE->name, THIS_MODULE->name)) != 0) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "GPIO IRQ Error\n");
        gpio_free(GPIO_IN);
        return err;
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Waiting for interrupts ... \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        counter = 0;
        mdelay(1000);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Frequency: %lu\n", counter);
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO "Done \n");    
    return 0; 
} 

static void __exit exemple_exit (void) 
{
    free_irq(gpio_to_irq(GPIO_IN), THIS_MODULE->name);  
    gpio_free(GPIO_IN);
}

module_init(exemple_init);
module_exit(exemple_exit);

MODULE_AUTHOR("Pierre LE COZ");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("GPIO interrupt");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: To handle 10 MHz interrupt you need latency better than 100 ns. Usual GPIO interrupt latency is in order of 1000 cycles (very depends), i.e. more than 1 us at 1.2 GHz.

Comment: whats solution?

Comment: Use hardware parallel FIFO chip with suitable interface. For example some high-speed USB FIFO chip or FPGA.

Comment: Do not use GPIO. This is the solution. The SPI is better for the applications like you showed on the picture.

Comment: Technically it is possible to read data clocked by 10 MHz on 1.2 GHz CPU with GPIO. You need a polling busy loop which iteration guaranteed to execute in less than 120 cycles, probably bound to a separate hardware core which do nothing except polling.

Comment: @dimich, true, but so-o-o wasteful from resource (power and compute) point of view.

Comment: @0andriy Sure. I'm not saying it's a good way. I did so only on bare metal MCUs without hardware multi-line SPI, which the only task was to detect a specific sequence in input data.

Comment: in SPI mode, max clock is 200MHz(datasheet), but when set to serial mode the clock is greater than 300MHz

Comment: So, you may read up to 20 data lines via shift register (like 74hc299) with a speed of 10MHz with SPI. You probably want to use DMA as well. Good luck!